# What is the major product for the reaction of (1R,2R)-2-methylcyclohexanol with hydrogen bromide?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

What is the major product for the reaction of (1*R*,2*R*)-2-methylcyclohexanol<sup>[1,2]</sup>  with hydrogen bromide? What will happen to the stereocenters?

[image: (1R,2R)-2-methylcyclohexanol]

I only know the $\ce{HBr}$ will somehow substitute the alcohol, but I'm not sure about the position or stereo chemistry of the final product.

1. CSID:22437, http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.22437.html (accessed 14:03, Oct 12, 2018)
2. National Center for Biotechnology Information. PubChem Compound Database; CID=24004, https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/24004 (accessed Oct. 12, 2018).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\ce{HBr}$ is a fairly strong acid; protonation of (1*R*,2*R*)-2-methylcyclohexanol (**1**) gives **1a**. Water is a pretty good leaving group and that's what it does, resulting in the secondary cation **1b**.

[image: 2-methylcyclohexanol-protonation]

Bad news: You have just lost one stereocentre.

You might remember that tertiary cations are more stable than secondary ones.
A 1,2 hydride shift converts **1b** into the more stable **1c**.
More bad news: The rearrangement has flattened the tertiary centre.
The nucleophile $\ce{Br-}$ can add from both sides of cation, yielding **2** as the major product.

[image: hydrogen shift]

Depending on the reaction conditions, minor products will arise from the addition of $\ce{Br-}$ to **1b**, or from elimination reactions.